# CSS3 Animation IE11 issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, animation

I've got strange problem with IE11.

Just created whole site with bunch of css3 animation and everything works great except one element animation in IE11 (other elements works in IE11).

Here is the code:

```
.arrow.forward {
        bottom:0px;
        animation:forwardarrow 0.3s 10s forwards;
    }
@keyframes forwardarrow {
    0% {
        bottom:0px;
    }
    100% {
        bottom:-18.5px;
    }
}
```

I think everything is fine with that - but this is only one element not working in IE11 - and in IE only.

When i inspect object in IE11 and disable animation:forwardarrow 0.3s 10s forwards; and then enable it back.. it's work but not on load...
... what is going on with that?

here are my meta tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9;IE=10;IE=Edge,chrome=1"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Try placing your keyframes definitions before any other CSS definitions please. Can you as well present your used meta tags?

Comment: I already placed them there they are before everything except @font-face

Comment: Your meta tags look fine as well, was looking for missing _IE=Edge_. Could you try replacing the _0%_ and _100%_ in your Keyframes with _from_ and _to_ respectively?

Comment: Yes, i was trying that too. But i found the answer. 
I know it was hard to answer not knowing about the parent, but i didn't know it was causing issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
.arrow.forward was nested in other html element that containes other animation.

Not sure why, but IE 11 doesn't want to animate child element.

So i've nested it with one other parent and everything works fine.

```
<div class="arrow-container">
    <div> <!-- aditional div to prevent parenting issues;) -->
        <div class="svg arrow click back" data-svgIcon="thin-arrow"></div>
        <div class="svg arrow click forward" data-svgIcon="thin-arrow"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```